# VS2008 Smart Device Project Template not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, project-template, smart-device

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition and cannot see the option to start a new smart device project (for windows mobile).

I have checked in the project installation directory and found that there is 5 templates.(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\SmartDevice\1033).

What could be the reason, the machine is a Windows Server 2008, may be this ?